# Why explicitly call ToString() method in MessageBox.show()?

Tags: c#

I gather that **`MessageBox.show()`** method accepts **string** argument and therefore we require **`ToString()`** method to call on the argument.

```
object k = 999;
MessageBox.Show(k.ToString());
```

But when it comes to **`Console.WriteLine()`**, it is smart enough to do this by itself. My question is **Why the difference?**

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` has an overload that accepts `object` (and that will call `ToString()` internally)

Comment: Does it really matter? Just build the message you want to show on the `MessageBox` and then pass it to `Show`. Why it is so? Maybe because the method wants to protect you from careless mistakes. If it allowed any kind of object it would be difficult to differentiate between the message and the other parameters that are possible in the overloads of [`Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx). `Console.Write` only accepts parameter that should be printed, not additional like `MessageBoxButtons`.

Comment: It makes sense, that this function intended to display >messages< only takes strings. The Console however has to use the text interface for all kinds of data, since it has no other option, so it supports convertion more.

Comment: MessageBox.Show already has 21 overloads that allow the caller to specify things like caption, buttons, icon, parent...).  This is already close to the upper limit for usability.

Comment: The MessageBox.Show() method has a lot of overloads with a *lot* of arguments of very different types.  That makes it quite dangerous to permit passing *object*.  Far too easy to pass, say, a MessageBoxButtons value when you meant a string, the compiler would not warn you about that.  Not an issue with Console.WriteLine().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,8c83114cc3fd109d

then you'll see that there are many overloads of the `WriteLine` function in the `Console` class, including `Console.WriteLine(Object value)`. This is very convenient.

`MessageBox.Show` lacks these different overloads and accepts "only" a string.

Answer (score 0):

[`Console.WriteLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) has many overloads, [one of which takes an `object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) and calls `ToString()` on it.

[`MessageBox.Show`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show(v=vs.110).aspx) has no similar overload - it must take a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the reference code or [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll see that `Console.WriteLine()` has a huge list of overloads.

There are versions for `int`, `double`, `decimal` etc... and versions for `object` arguments. So if you write

```
object k = 999;
Console.WriteLine(k);
```

the overload `Console.WriteLine(object o)` is used which internally itself calls `k.ToString()`.

`MessageBox.Show()` on the other hand only has overload taking a `string` as argument for the text to show, and the `object` `k` cannot be implicitly casted to `string`. Thatswhy you have to call `k.ToString()` yourself.